# Is there a way to make minecraft java edition commandblock code into minecraft bedrock edition commandblock code?

Tags: minecraft

I want to make a trading system in my minecraft bedwars game. [Here is the video I used.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxtLj-RgHag&ab_channel=OMGcraft-MinecraftTips%26Tutorials%21)

[Here is the website I used.](https://www.digminecraft.com/generators/villager_trade.php)

Here is the minecraft java edition code I have:

```
/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {VillagerData:

{profession:armorer,level:2,type:plains},Invulnerable:1,Silent:1,NoAI:1,CustomName:"\"Trader\"",Offers:

{Recipes:[{buy:{id:gold_ingot,Count:5},sell:{id:red_wool,Count:32,tag:{display:{Name:"\"Wool

\""}}},rewardExp:0b,maxUses:9999999}]}}
```

I want to make minecraft java edition code into minecraft bedrock edition code.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible yet in Bedrock edition, well at least through commands. If your up for the challenge, this is possible using trade tables through behaviour packs. I find [THIS](https://wiki.bedrock.dev/loot/trade-tables.html) documentation from [Bedrock Dev](https://wiki.bedrock.dev) to be most useful.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can change the NBT tag of your Villager with 3rd-party software.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately Bedrock edition does not support NBT data in commands and your command contains NBT data so there is no way to port this to bedrock, sorry!